# Why procmail didn't match this rule?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, email-filter, procmail

I have the following rule to send all emails with suspicious attachments to a dedicated folder:

```
# Emails with attachments
:0
* ^Content-Type: multipart/
{
  :0 B
  * ^Content-Type: application/(zip|x-zip-compressed)|\
    ^Content-Type:.*name=.*\.(zip|exe|rar|rtf|docm)|\
    ^Content-.*attachment.*name=.*\.(zip|exe|rar|rtf|docm)|\
    ^Content-.*application.octet-stream.*name=.*\.(zip|exe|rar|rtf|docm)
  $L/.3_my._quarantine/
}
```

However I just noticed that an email with a zip attachment slipped through it, and I can't figure out why (my@email and myemail contained my email and my host which I obfuscated):

```
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
From: scanner47578858@myemail.com
To: "my@email.com"
 <my@email.com>
Subject: Attached File
Date:Mon, 16 May 2016 17:16:47 +0530
Message-Id: <272843899191709486.0001.scannerTxNo.0051@scannerF04EF6.myemail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="53594271E1EBE7BBDAF4BBA9"

--53594271E1EBE7BBDAF4BBA9
Content-Type: application/x-compressed;
 name="my@email.com_3602848_97891076672132.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="my@email.com_3602848_97891076672132.zip"
```

AFAICS `^Content-Type:.*name=.*\.(zip|exe|rar|rtf|docm)` should match? Is it because of quotation marks?

Comment: I don't use `procmail`, but it looks as though the configuration lines might require to match a full line, in which case, because the name is on a separate line from the classification, you may need to insert the line `^ .*name=.*\.(zip|exe|rar|rtf|docm)|\ ` into your configuration.

Comment: That's what I thought but apparently procmail expands folded headers when matching the condition. I found many resources claiming the same and I assume this is something else unless proved otherwise. See this for example among others: https://www.mhonarc.org/archive/html/procmail/2006-06/msg00119.html

Comment: Sorry, I was grasping at straws. Otherwise, as you say, the expression looks OK.

Comment: Kudos for including a short, representative test message as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post you link to does indeed state that folded *headers* are handled correctly, but this recipe is examining the body, not a header.

It is a misfeature of Procmail that it doesn't recognize MIME structures correctly; this would be an important addition to a modern mail filter; but alas, Procmail development ceased already in the early 2000s (and already once before then, when the original developer let go).

As a crude workaround, you could temporarily split a MIME multipart message on the MIME boundary, and feed each part to a separate Procmail recipe, but this quickly becomes brittle and complex (in theory, MIME messages could be nested arbitrarily deeply, though for most practical purposes, you only need to recurse one or two levels down -- anything beyond that is probably a bounce or something like that, not directly a feature of the message you are examining).

Because your regex has only a few possible (realistic!) split points, you can refactor it to account for possible line breaks:

```
:0
* ^Content-type: multipart/
{
  :0B
  * ^Content-Type: application/(zip|x-zip-compressed)|\
    ^Content-Type:.*(($)[   ].*)*name=.*\.(zip|exe|rar|rtf|docm)|\
    ^Content-.*attachment.*(($)[    ].*)*name=.*\.(zip|exe|rar|rtf|docm)|\
    ^Content-.*application.octet-stream.*(($)[  ].*)*name=.*\.(zip|exe|rar|rtf|docm)
  $L/.3_my._quarantine/
}
```

You'll notice the `(($)[    ].*)*` addition in a few places.  This accounts for a possible newline (`($)`) followed by a whitespace character (tab or space, `[     ]`) followed by anything, repeated zero or more times.

(As an aside, this would perhaps be slightly easier to debug with scoring:

```
  :0 B
  * 1^1 ^Content-Type: application/(zip|x-zip-compressed)
  * 1^1 ^Content-Type:.*(($)[   ].*)*name=.*\.(zip|exe|rar|rtf|docm)
  * 1^1 ^Content-.*attachment.*(($)[    ].*)*name=.*\.(zip|exe|rar|rtf|docm)
  * 1^1 ^Content-.*application.octet-stream.*(($)[  ].*)*name=.*\.(zip|exe|rar|rtf|docm)
  ...
```

With this, you can see in the `VERBOSE=yes` log the result of each individual regex in this complex multi-regex recipe.)

If you need a completely watertight recipe, perhaps write a simple script in Python or Perl (or Ruby or ... what have you) to normalize the MIME structure.  I remember there was a tool called `emil` a long time ago which did something like this, but it was never very well-established, let alone well-documented. (In fact, IIRC it was designed specifically to plug into pre-MIME `sendmail`, and was near-impossible to use for anything else.)

Comment: Oh, great! I knew that headers are folded automatically and that procmail doesn't work with MIME parts properly but somehow didn't make a connection between those two. Your answer completely makes sense. Thanks!